# Is there a functional difference between PublicAPIAttribute and UsedImplicitlyAttribute?

Tags: resharper

Using ReSharper's annotations, the two annotations [`PublicAPIAttribute`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#PublicAPIAttribute) and [`UsedImplicitlyAttribute`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#UsedImplicitlyAttribute) appear to behave the same while using it in Visual Studio.

Is there any functional difference that I am overlooking between these two attributes, and if so what is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the difference is purely semantic to help you see why the symbol is not used in your code. Functionally, they both disable inspections that detect unused symbols.